# "TypeError: expected string or buffer" when filtering list with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am currently trying to apply regex in order to filter out certain links out of a list consisting of links.

I've tried it in severals ways now but I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Documents/pyp/pushbullet_updater/DoDa/test.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(get_chapter_links(links))
  File "/Users/User/Documents/pyp/pushbullet_updater/DoDa/test.py", line 15, in get_chapter_links
    match = re.findall(r"https://bluesilvertranslations\.wordpress\.com/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/douluo-dalu-\d{1,3}-\s*/", link)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/re.py", line 210, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#Gets chapter links
def get_chapter_links(index_url):
    r = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    url_list = []
    for url in links:
        url_list.append((url.get('href')))

    for link in url_list: # Iterates through every line and looks for a match:
        match = re.findall(r"https://bluesilvertranslations\.wordpress\.com/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/douluo-dalu-\d{1,3}-\s*/", link)
    return match

links = 'https://bluesilvertranslations.wordpress.com/chapter-list/'

print(get_chapter_links(links))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**`re`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) docs

```
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

New in version 1.5.2.

Changed in version 2.4: Added the optional flags argument.
```

**Note:**

- The first argument should be a pattern and the second argument should be a string

**Modified Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#Gets chapter links
def get_chapter_links(index_url):
    r = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    url_list = []
    for url in links:
        url_list.append((url.get('href')))
    match = [] # Create a list and append to it the matched links 
    for link in url_list: # Iterates through every line and looks for a match:
        if link: # I have added this to see in there are value in link.
            match += re.findall(r"https://bluesilvertranslations\.wordpress\.com/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}/douluo-dalu-\d{1,3}-.*/", link) # I have changed the regex a bit since your did not match
    return match

links = 'https://bluesilvertranslations.wordpress.com/chapter-list/'

print(get_chapter_links(links))
```